# Re-Using already fetched data from server in android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-listview

I am populating a listview with data(Text,image Urls etc) fetched from server.
This data might be updated at server side weekly/monthly.
What i want is , **when my application loads the listview first time, the data fetched from server is stored at application/client side, so as to be re-used later in redrawing the listview.**How can i acheive that.

One Possible Solution is:

1. Use Application class to download this data first time, store it in SQLlite db and always fetch results from DB while drawing a listview.Later i can use GCM Send-To-Sync tickles to update the sqldb data.
   -**Querying db everytime a listview is to be drawn, is it not a good practice.??**
   Any common practice to achieve this.

Any views about using Loaders/Loading Manager.

**EDIT**

The data in questions is a jsonpackage. With structure like(consider array size as 100 at max.)

```
 [ // JSON Array
         { // JSON Object
         "rank":1,"country":"China",
         "population":"1,354,040,000",

         "flag":"http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/china.png"
         }, (
     ]
```

Comment: I don't exactly know what kind of data you are storing, so can't comment specifically. You can also create file structure in internal/external storage also. Loaders you can use to query data from db. Don't query db if the data can be cached, either in main memory or in a dump somewhere in internal storage (like a db snapshot, until updated).

Comment: @hbansal added the data sample

Comment: Posting an answer below with sample code, as I told earlier, all answers are just possible implementations, you have to decide for yourself and choose wisely. Also, keep in mind the memory usage of your data sets, that will effect how you design this system.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to store the data fetched from server to database itself and then, bind the data from `SQLiteDatabase` to `ListView`

It cannot be said that **Querying db everytime a listview is to be drawn, is it not a good practice..**, because you need to fetch data only once when the activity is started or when the data within database is changed.

*Re-Using already fetched data from server...* means that you need a persistent storage and the storage should be updated periodically or on some user request.

Comment: you said "you need to fetch data only once when the activity is started or when the data within database is changed.", How can i do that.If i draw listview first time with the results from query to db,how can i later use the same fetched results..? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of data you have. Generally if it in a json package coming from the server then you can just keep that raw json and parse and populate the data on every app launch. But this will only be helpful if the amount of data is **not** too large. If the amount of data you have at any given moment is huge then you will have to parse and store the formatted data to a SQL DB, query and fetch the data on every app launch.

Also in case of manageable amount of data you can keep the data in-memory for the duration of the app lifecycle using static data model instances.

There can be multiple ways in which you can solve this problem but it all depends on how much data do you have and in what format and accordingly you take a call on which methodology will fetch you the best performance.

Comment: Yes it is a Json package.what can be classified as huge data? if i have say a json array with at max say, 100 Json Objects(each object has say 4-5 string variables) what way would you suggest  to adopt? thanks

Comment: 10,000+ is generally considered a large chunk of data. Anything below that, the system can handle easily. Then again it depends on what range of devices you are targeting.

Comment: 100 json objects is very small data set and you can just save it in a text file in sdcard and read it at launch time

Comment: please see my answer below for my implementation. Do you see any issues with that approach?

Answer (score 0):

Create a directory in sdcard/internal storage, whichever is available using this static method.

```
/**
* Cache class to create dir, save, retrieve and delete files
* File names are hashCode of the url json is downloaded from.
**/
public class FileCache {

    static File cacheDir;
    static final String DIRECTORY_ADDRESS = "/Android/data/<app_package>/.<directory name>";

    public static createDirectory(Context context){
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            cacheDir=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),DIRECTORY_ADDRESS);
        else
            cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
        if(!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
    }    

    public static File getFile(String url){
        String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
        File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
        return f;
    }

    public static void saveFile(InputStream is, File file){
        try {
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
            copyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    /**
    * Clear all files at app uninstall or application or on 
    * low memory or some other event, using a boradcastreceiver/alarmmanager
    **/
    public static void clear(){
        File[] files=cacheDir.listFiles();
        if(files==null)
            return;
        for(File f:files)
            f.delete();
    }
}
```

Now create directory when application starts:

```
FileCache.createDirectory(context);
```

Once this is set, you have to fetch your JSONArray using an AsyncTask, store store it in a file

```
/**
* Add this in doinBackground()
**/
private File getJson(Stirng url) {
    File f = FileCache.getFile(url);
    if(f != null && f.isFile()) {
        //file exists in directory, no need to download.
        return f;
    }

    try {
        URL fileUrl = new URL(url);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) fileUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(120000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(120000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);

        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        FileCache.saveFile(is, f);

        return f;                      
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now you have to run this thread every time you need to load and bind the data into listview. I am excluding the details, of how you will parse the json from file and convert it into List for the Adapter.

This AsyncTask will automatically fetch the data if not available in file, and load into listview, in onPostExecute(). So, from the 2nd time, it wont take much time, and data will be persisted in storage. You can also add pagination in the ListView, i.e if you have 1000 json hashes, you can read data from this file in batches, that will also be a good optimization.

Now, whenever the data gets updated (monthly/weekly), send a push notification using GCM, run a service, clear the old file using FileCache.clear(), and start this AsyncTask from the service, all in the background, so if the app is opened afterwards, you will get updated data from file storage.

Putting everything in sqlite is a similar alternative, then you have to use DbAdapters, CursorLoaders and CursorAdapters, and then using the service to update the db.

But since you dont have large data sets, I think file caching is sufficient.

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: please see my answer below. do you see any issue with that approach?

Comment: Don't use large chunks in SharePref, its only meant to store primitive key=>value pairs.

Comment: thx.. looking at your above solution , you mentioned _"Now create directory when application starts:"_  wont that always make a new directory or overwrite prev one whenever app is started?.

Comment: Nope, look at this part,  if(!cacheDir.exists()) cacheDir.mkdirs();

Comment: silly missout ..sorry...thx... btw can i just use  cache directory and not use external storage, i guess that ll avoid data unavailablility when ext storage is unavailable.

Comment: But there is a limit to internal storage, also some devices may not have either of them, hence use this way, wherever possible it will create cache dir, you can 1st check for internal storage if you want, but its always good to keep a fail-safe check.

Comment: i tried yur above code. There is a problem in createDirectory() method, it always creates a new directory,whenever application is started afresh.Also 

`File f = FileCache.getFile(url);
if(f != null && f.isFile()) {  
//Never True
}`
Always a new File is created

Please have  a look

Answer (score 0):

I implemented as below:

**(If you see any issues in the implementation,performance wise or  any please comment)**

1. Fetch Data(Json Array with a length of 50 ) from server for first time, store it as a string(JsonArray.toString()) in **sharedpreferences** and populate the listview.
2. When required to display the listview again, get stored jsonarraystring from sharedpreferences ,convert it back to jsonarray and populate the listview.
3. To get updated data from server, send a GCM tickle to update stored sharedpreferences array with new value in background.

This approach is working fine so far. Do you guys see any issues i can face at anystage.
ThankYou

Comment: 1. Sharedpreferences is not inteded to store large chunks of data. In this case your json array is big for a key value pair based storage system. easier option would be to just store it on the SD Card
2. Keep the parsed data in memory for the duration the app is alive. No point parsing the same data again and again since the total data is not large enough
3. Dont finish your activities until it is really required by your application flow. From what I can perceive the list view is on the main screen of the app and will need to be displayed again and again.

Comment: +1 FunkyIdol, we should not add large chunks of data in SharedPreferences, its better to use sdcard instead.